# UIView Animation doesn't fire when called from different view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewanimation

I'm calling a method from another view controller by using this:

```
   InitialViewController *secondController = [[InitialViewController alloc] init];
   [secondController forecast];
```

Here's the method in the InitialViewController:

```
-(void)forecast{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Forecast" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    self.customPager.frame = CGRectMake(0,5, 320, 510);
    self.view1.frame = CGRectMake(-320,5, 320, 510);
    radarView.frame = CGRectMake(0,560, 320, 510);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSLog(@"Method Passed");
}
```

In my console, I get the NSLog "Method Passed", but the UIView animation does not occur at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are not displaying in any way the view associated to `secondController`. I.e., after doing:

```
InitialViewController *secondController = [[InitialViewController alloc] init];
```

I would expect you do something like:

```
[self.view addSubview:secondController.view];
```

This would trigger `loadView/viewDidLoad` before you call `forecast`. Furthermore, I would give a chance to the UI to be show your view before animating it; thus, I would call `forecast` either like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(forecast) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

or from `viewDidAppear`.

EDIT:

According to your comment,
your `InitialViewController` is already displayed on screen. In this case, what you should do is getting a reference to it and sending it the `forecast` message.

What you are doing now is instantiating a new `InitialViewController` (and then sending the `forecast` message to it) that has no relation with the one already displayed.

Comment: Hi!, the InitialViewController is already loaded on the screen, and I'm calling it from a side menu bar view controller

Comment: If your `InitialViewController` is already on screen, get a reference to it and send it the `forecast` message; you are instantiating a new `InitialViewController` that has no relation with the one already displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you instantiate `secondController`, its view is never displayed on screen, or even loaded, so any animations that you apply to it have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If your second controller is already on the screen, then your alloc init is creating another one, not getting the one already present (the log works because you are creating an instance of InitialViewController, so its code will run, but another instance's view is the one you're seeing on screen). You need to get a reference to the one on screen. I can't say how you should do that without knowing how you got your 2 controllers on the screen in the first place.